# invoking copy constructor inside other constructor

Tags: c++, placement-new

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class A
{
public:
    std::string s;
    A()
    {
        s = "string";
        new(this)A(*this);
    }
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout<<a.s;
    return 0;
}
```

I get empty string in output. What does the C++ standard say about such behaviour?

Comment: Auwgh, I really need some coffee now.

Comment: I got 'string' on output with GCC 4.5

Comment: is this: `new(this)A(*this);`invoking copy constructor inside other constructor?

Comment: `stdlib.h` => `cstdlib` but the header is unnecessary here anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [placement new to defer to a different constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668144/placement-new-to-defer-to-a-different-constructor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be at least two problems here:

- You try to initialize A with a copy of itself
- Inside the constructor, A isn't yet fully constructed, so you cannot really copy it

Not to mention that `new(this)` is suspect in itself.

Comment: `new(this)` is fine. And assigning to something with a copy of itself is usually also guaranteed to work (a copy assignment operator needs to guard against self-assignment) – copy construction, on the other hand, is a different matter.

Comment: @Konrad: So default (generated) copy ctor is guarded against self-assignment and therefore actual copying isn't performed? Seems that intermediate variable A a(*this); new(this)(a); solves the "problem" ?

Comment: @user396672 Nothing of the sort. The default *copy assignment operator* guards against self-assignment. I don’t think the default copy constructor does, simply because this case should normally never occur.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `s`'s constructor twice in a row by doing this, ergo, the behavior is undefined (and most likely some memory is leaked).